# CGAL handle to iterator comparison

Tags: cgal

I've read up on forums that CGAL iterator/circulator are type-castable to corresponding handles implicitly. I should be able to use iterators/circulators "as if they were handles". Why then I get an error if I try to compare them? Here is an example:

```
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds> CDT;
typedef CDT::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef CDT::Vertex_iterator Vertex_iterator;
...
CDT cdt;
Vertex_handle va = cdt.insert(Point(0,0));
for(Vertex_iterator i=cdt.vertices_begin();...) {
  va=i;  /* Compiles Ok */
  if(va==i) { ... } /* Pages of Error messages */
}
```

This example is adapted from [CGAL Delaunay meshing demo](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/Mesh_2_2mesh_global_8cpp-example.html)

Comment: Vertex_handle is the same as All_vertices_iterator, while Vertex_iterator is an alias for Finite_vertices_iterator (it would be clearer to use this name in your code). The second one is a boost::filter_iterator on the first one, so I would expect an implicit conversion that would make your code work, but apparently not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple...

```
for(Vertex_iterator i=cdt.vertices_begin();...) 
{
  va=i; /* Implicit dereferencing */
  /* Implicit deref. doesn't work, so use explicit dereferencing */       
  if(va==Vertex_handle(i)) { ... }
}
```